# Oracle file loader adding record with last character from skipped line

Tags: oracle

I am loading a CSV file into Oracle using the ORACLELOADER.  For some reason that I cannot discern the loader is adding a record from the first line that is being skipped. The row is the last character from the last header row.

The output from Oracle:

[image: Oracle]

The output from VIM w/ line ending:

[image: VIM]

Here is the SQL for the loader:

```
CREATE TABLE workorder
{
    work_order_number varchar2 (4000 char),
    work_order_status varchar2 (4000 char),
    work_order_date varchar2 (4000 char),
    maintenance_plan_id varchar2 (4000 char)
}
ORGANIZATIONAL EXTERNAL
{
    TYPE ORACLE LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY "IMPORT"
    ACCESS PARAMETERS
    {
         records delimited BY '\r\n' Skip 1
         Badfile REJECTED:  'work_order.bad'
         nologfile
         fields terminated by '~'
         missing field VALUES are NULL
    }
    LOCATION
    {
        'work_order.csv'
    }
}
REJECT LIMIT 0;
```

Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

EDIT (6/16/20): I have still been unable to determine the cause of this.  I have attempted to update the file with Unix style line endings, but no joy.  I have also noticed that this appears to be happening on other files, but I am currently unsure of the similarities between them.

Comment: Did you check the bad file?

Comment: @JimMacaulay The file is loading fine other than that first record, which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Use this property OPTIONS (SKIP=1) to skip the header row

Comment: Doesn't the `records delimited BY '\r\n' Skip 1` do the same thing?  It is skipping the first line, except for the last character in the row.